# Custom preference center example from

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api, cloudpage

In official documentation there is the option to download the custom profile center example code.

[**Creating a Custom Profile Center Using AMPScript and the SOAP API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm)

However when trying to use that code in CloudPages then the preview will never load and opening the published page will give an error.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but what?

Just for reference, I was not able to get a simple piece of code to work either in Cloud Pages (design view, HTML gear) it also never loaded the page.

The idea is to display data from Data Extension and have the Publication List subscription options available.

Comment: were you able to figure out a solution to this? I too am having trouble with this.

Comment: Hi @neo2049 - yes, I wrote a custom subscription center via SSJS/AMPscript instead, it works quicker and works well between MC and SF.

Comment: Is there a basic version that I can use to replace profile centre. I require it because we're going to use multi-org connector and the standard version doesn't work. I tried creating a cloud page with the example code but got the same problem you got.